# data.table subset on two columns where either key matches

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to `data.table` and seem to be missing something obvious. I have a table:

```
DT = data.table(A = c("x","y","y","z"), B = c("y","x","x","z"), value = 1:4)
setkey(DT, A, B)
```

Now I want to find all rows where either `A` or `B` is `"y"` (using binary search, my actual tables are larger and the operation has to be performed millions of times). I couldn't figure out how to do this in one statement, since,

```
DT[.("y", "y"), nomatch=0]
```

Gives me only rows where `(A & B) == "y"` (but I want `(A | B) == "y"`). What I'm doing now is:

```
uA <- unique(DT[, A])
rbind(DT[.(uA, "y"), nomatch=0], DT[.("y"), nomatch=0])
```

But I feel like there must be a more intuitive way.

Thanks for you help!

---

## Benchmark

Including code adapted from [@Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438190/r-data-table-binary-search-dt-with-key-on-two-columns-using-alternative-instea#comment58576535_35438190) on [Binary search DT with key on two columns using alternative (OR) instead of a conjunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438190/binary-search-dt-with-key-on-two-columns-using-alternative-or-instead-of-a-con)

```
n = 1e6
DT = data.table(A = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE), 
                B = sample(letters, n, replace = TRUE), value = 1:n)
setkey(DT, A, B)
uA <- unique(DT[, A])

library(microbenchmark)
Union = function(){
   mya = DT[A=="y", which=TRUE]
   myb = DT[B=="y", which=TRUE]
   DT[union(mya,myb)] 
} 
microbenchmark(
    "reduce" = DT[DT[, Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, '==', 'y')), .SDcols = A:B]],
    "rbind" = rbind(DT[.(uA, "y"), nomatch=0], DT[.("y"), nomatch=0]),
    "union" = Union()
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 reduce 9.922728 10.116613 11.422823 10.226871 11.803204 25.453557   100
  rbind 2.596139  2.734751  2.916620  2.850199  3.113995  3.453326   100
  union 5.393815  5.725917  6.221544  5.906222  6.758622 14.019206   100
```

Comment: You may use `DT[DT[, Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, '==', 'y')), .SDcols = A:B]]`

Comment: Great thanks, that works! (And it's twice as fast as my solution). I'm surprised though that there is not a more intuitive way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik, missed that one in my research

Comment: @Henrik could you post that code as an answer? I couldn't get that solution to produce equivalent output.

Comment: @Hendrik see my edits. I got it to work but it seems slower, too.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `Reduce` with `|` to get a logical `vector` that checks either ones of the columns mentioned in the `.SDcols` have the value 'y' and use it for subsetting the rows

```
DT[DT[, Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, '==', 'y')), .SDcols = A:B]]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
DT = data.table(A = sample(letters, 1e7, replace = TRUE), 
                B = sample(letters, 1e7, replace = TRUE), value = 1:1e7)

DT1 <- copy(DT)
system.time({
      setkey(DT, A, B)
    uA <- unique(DT[, A])
    rbind(DT[.(uA, "y"), nomatch=0], DT[.("y"), nomatch=0])
     })
# user  system elapsed 
#  1.14    0.19    0.87 

system.time({
   DT1[DT1[, Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, '==', 'y')), .SDcols = A:B]]
   })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.17    0.02    0.19
```

Comment: I just checked it again and this solution actually is only faster for small tables. For larger tables it scales poorly (does it maybe use a vector scan?). See the edit to my question

Comment: @FridolinLinder  You are not including the `setkey` option in the benchmark.  Also, try to check with more number of columns i.e. 15 or so

Comment: @FridolinLinder  I added the system.time which will also consider the `setkey`.  I am not using the microbenchmark, because one the setkey is done, the repeated actions will be faster.  Also, you can consider that if there are more number of columns, then the method with `rbind` could become tedious

Comment: Does that mean that your solution doesn't rely on `setkey()`? (Sorry I don't completely understand the details). In that case, I would lose the benefit of ordering the data once and then getting the speedup for the binary search. That's specific to my application, but on the other hand, data.tables binary search never gives you a speedup if the ordering step would be repeated on each subsetting operation.

Comment: @FridolinLinder  No, if you check my solution, I am using a copy of 'DT" and it doesn't have any `key` i.e. `key(DT)#
[1] "A" "B";
 key(DT1)
#NULL`  You definitely get a speed up, if the setkey timings are not considered.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. If it doesn't have a key, it does a (linear) vector search every time I repeat the subsetting operation (which is O(n). Whereas if a key is set once (time consuming) every following operation is O(log n). I should have probably emphasized more in my question that the subsetting operation is repeated often (millions of times) so it worth spending some time once to order the data (`setkey()`). I appreciate your answer though!

Comment: @FridolinLinder  Okay, I got it.  But, suppose if you have a 5 or 6 columns to do this, then I am not sure how your `rbind` task would be done and that too could involve multiple steps based on your code